# Buttons and text won't stay within container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container with some text and buttons that are responsive to the screen size, but they extend off the side of the container when there's not enough room. Someone helped me fix it by adding a clamp parameter to the font-size, but after I made a few adjustments to other parts of my code, now the problem is back.

Could someone help me figure out what I need to do to keep the buttons and text within the container? I thought I needed to adjust the min values of the clamp parameter, but that doesn't seem to change anything. It doesn't seem like the text and buttons even recognizes the parent container, they just kind of do what they want.

I have the btn-grid container set to 20% of the height of the chat_bubble, and I need the text to stay within that remaining 80% of the container.

Besides that, I'm getting a warning from WebStorm that several of my font-size declarations over-write each other, but I can't figure out which one is supposed to take priority to avoid being redundant.

Also I'm trying to add a 5vw or percent margin/padding to the top and right of the main container, but I notice that when I do a scrollbar appears even if I do overflow: hidden. Someone told me this is because of margin collapsing, but I can't figure out how to prevent that from happening because I don't see how the nested containers are taking up so much space.

This is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/JjWVbKJ

And this is my code:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Benne', serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.5rem, 2rem);
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

:root {
    --hue-neutral: 200;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
}

#question {
    font-size: 1.5rem; /* fallback */
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.5rem, 2rem);
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    height: 20%;
}

.btn {
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.5rem, 2rem);
}

.btn:hover {
    border-color: black;
}

.start-btn, .next-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.5rem, 2rem);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    display: flex; /* Use flexbox */
    flex-direction: row; /* Flex horizontally */
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding-left: 5vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#chat_bubble {
    width: 70vw; /* Make chat bubble 70% of viewport width */
    height: 70vh; /* Make chat bubble 70% of viewport height */
    background: ghostwhite !important;
}

#character_image  {
    float: none; /* undo float */
    flex-shrink: 1; /* let character image shrink */
    height: 70vh; /* Make character_image 70% of viewport height */
}

#character_image img {
    height: 100%;
}

#char_1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
#char_2 {
    display: none;
}
@media(max-width:700px) {
    #main {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #chat_bubble {
        width: 90vw;
    }
    #character_image {
        height: 30vh;
    }
    #char_1 {
        display: none;
    }
    #char_2 {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the explicit `height: 70vh` declaration on `#chat_bubble` and instead use `min-height: 70vh` to ensure that the height is at minimum 70% of the viewport height, the content wont overflow. Now, the text and buttons won't ever overflow the parent container as there isn't an explicit height set on the parent `#chat_bubble`. The reason the buttons overflow before this change is because the explicit width of 70vh is set on `#chat_bubble` and any nested content that is long enough to extend outside of the parent container will do so. I added a top/bottom margin of `5vw` and auto left/right margins, you can adjust these as you see fit.

After reading your comments below, the `clamp()` usage is part of the problem for the text taking up so much space on the screen and forcing the `#chat_bubble` to have a large height. The syntax is `clamp(min, flex unit, max)` and your using `1.5rem` for the 2nd arg, instead use a viewport unit like `3vw` or anything with `vw` as the middle argument which is the "scale" or "flex-unit" so to speak.

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')
const emailContainerElement = document.getElementById('email-container')
const submitEmailButton = document.getElementById('submit-email-btn')
const email = document.getElementById('email')
const chartContainer = document.getElementById('chart')

startButton.classList.add('hide')
emailContainerElement.classList.add('hide')
questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')

questionElement.innerText = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'

const button_no = document.createElement('button')
button_no.innerText = 'No'
button_no.classList.add('btn')
answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button_no)
const button_yes = document.createElement('button')
button_yes.innerText = 'No'
button_yes.classList.add('btn')
answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button_yes)
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Benne', serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.5rem, 2rem);
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

:root {
    --hue-neutral: 200;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
}

#question {
    font-size: 1.5rem; /* fallback */
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    height: 20%;
}

.btn {
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
}

.btn:hover {
    border-color: black;
}

.start-btn, .next-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.5rem, 2rem);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    display: flex; /* Use flexbox */
    flex-direction: row; /* Flex horizontally (this is default flex-direction)*/
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin: 5vw auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#chat_bubble {
    width: 70vw; /* Make chat bubble 70% of viewport width */
    min-height: 70vh; /* Make chat bubble 70% of viewport height at minimum*/
    background: ghostwhite !important;
}

#character_image  {
    float: none; /* undo float */
    flex-shrink: 1; /* let character image shrink */
    height: 70vh; /* Make character_image 70% of viewport height */
}

#character_image img {
    height: 100%;
}

#char_1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
#char_2 {
    display: none;
}
@media(max-width:700px) {
    #main {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #chat_bubble {
        width: 90vw;
    }
    #character_image {
        height: 30vh;
    }
    #char_1 {
        display: none;
    }
    #char_2 {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test title</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Benne&family=Fjalla+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="chat_bubble" class="container">
        <div id="email-container" class="hide">
            <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
            <button id="submit-email-btn" class="btn">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div id="question-container" class="hide">
            <div id="question" class="question-text">Question</div>
            <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="chart" class="hide"></div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="character_image">
      <img id="char_1" src="https://i.imgur.com/7eYWqqo.png" alt=""></img>
  <img id="char_2" src="https://i.imgur.com/ixM8TtU.png" alt=""></img>
    </div>

</div>


<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script defer src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @TheNomadicAspie Does this help answer your question?

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to have the text and buttons fit in the parent container without making the chat bubble bigger? I intentionally wanted chat_bubble to be exactly the size it is now relative to the screen, and I've been trying to get the sizing of the containers right for several days. Now the only thing left is I want the text and buttons to fit dynamically within that container. Making the container larger isn't my preferred option if there's anyway to avoid that.

Comment: Ah, yes I see. So you want the `#main` container to occupy 100% of the viewport height and not have any vertical scroll. Just have the `#chat_bubble` occupy its portion of the screen along with the image without having any vertical scrolling appear. Thank you for the explanation, that makes more sense. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, it's confusing to explain because the rules are different depending on the screen size. But basically if the screen is over 700px wide, it's ok for the chat bubble to get larger or smaller because computer monitors have plenty of room for the amount of text. But for mobile or small devices, I want the character image to take up 30% of the vertical height and for the chat bubble to take up the remaining vertical and horizontal space (Except for a margin on the left, top, and right which is where I'm having issues with the scroll bar).

Comment: But yeah, I have everything almost exactly how I want it except for the issues with the text and buttons. Which were fixed before when you helped me, but then when I needed to adjust the size of the containers it no longer worked properly. Thank you again so much for your help. I've been doing this all day every day for awhile now, and I'm really new to CSS so it's really overwhelming.

Comment: @TheNomadicAspie Your welcome, I'm happy to help. I updated my answer if you want to have a look. Let me know if that is closer to what you need :)

Comment: That's perfect, thank you again. I've just been resizing the window cheerfully for the past several minutes, in awe that this finally works exactly the way I wanted it to. I don't even have the words to explain how much I appreciate it. I wish there was a super upvote button.

Comment: Ok great! And no problem. I'm happy it works the way you need it too. Happy coding :)

Comment: Actually, I hope you don't mind but I have one more question. Do you know how I can get rid of the scrollbar that appears when the screen is smaller? I thought having overflow: hidden on main would prevent that, is it because of the margins?

Comment: Sure thing, I dont mind at all. Just add `overflow: hidden` to the `body`. Its not because of the margins, the `overflow` is just `auto` by default so when the screen is smaller it scrolls a bit. I updated my answer with `overflow: hidden` added to the body so it doesn't scroll for mobile viewports.